# Filtering for "[tag-a] AND [tag-b]" only offers updates for [tag-b]

Tags: bug, search, filtering, tag-search, web-sockets

#### Description

When searching for an intersection of tags `[tag-a] AND [tag-b]` or the equivalent `[tag-a] [tag-b]` the search results show questions tagged with both the tags. When the order of results is further set to **Newest**, the page will offer the in-page refresh when new items that match the filter criteria are posted.

The problem is that when using an AND filter, the "new items posted" are only filtered by *the last tag in the search*.

#### Steps to reproduce:

1. Search for two tags on a stack site. For example, on Stack Overflow search for [`[javascript] [java]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+java).
2. Set the ordering to **Newest**.
3. Wait (both JavaScript and Java are quite active, so you don't have to wait for long).
4. When you get the in-page notifications that new questions are posted, click it and load the new questions.

Expected: the newly loaded questions have both the tags. 
Actual: the newly loaded questions only have the *last tag* in the search.

#### Screenshots

Before loading:

[image: Filter for JavaScript and Java tags set to show the newest. The page shows questions with both. There is a notification saying "4 questions with new activity".]

After loading:

[image: The same page with filter for JavaScript and Java tags set to show the newest. The loaded questions all have the Java tag but not JavaScript.]

#### Additional notes

- If a new question is posted with *both* the tags, then it is still going to be loaded as new, since it matches the last tag in the search.
- The exact same behaviour is present when filtering for three tags: `[tag-a] AND [tag-b] AND [tag-c]` will only show updates for [tag-c].
- I am certain the position in the filters is the key factor. Changing the order of the search to `[tag-b] AND [tag-a]` will show updates for `[tag-a]` instead.
- Same behaviour is seen in custom filters.